# How to supply MS SQL data to Google Charts

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql-server

I have a website in which I use Visual Studio's built in charts to visualize data.

I use c# methods to provide the chart with a datasource. However, google charts require the data on javascript methods. I have done some research on how to provide the data to a javascript method but I came up empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
           google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
           google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
           function drawChart() {
               var data = new google.visualization.DataTable('<%=t%>');

               var options = {
                   title: 'Company Performance'
               };

               var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
               chart.draw(data, options);
           }
    </script>
```

In this example I tried to create a data table called "t" on the c# side. I debugged and saw that data table is filled correctly but I keep getting "Table has no columns" error.

So, Can anyone provide a walkthrough on how to supply my MSSQL data into the javascript method used by google charts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See this [Google Line Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

First Change

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable('<%=t%>');
```

to

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable('<%=t%>');
```

Now as discussed here [Google Line Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) you should use **Array of Array** not the C# DataTable object. Convert you DataTable to **Array of Array** and then pass it to arrayToDataTable() function.

Comment: I use a List<Object> to retrieve the data from database then I turned it into a DataTable, per your suggestion I tried turning it into an array but it doesn't allow me to create a multidimensional array.

Comment: @CanCanbek please provide the C# code through which you are trying to create multidimensional array.

Comment: new google.visualization.DataTable('<%=table.Cast<Object>().ToArray()%>')
Tried this but didn't work.

Comment: @CanCanbek this will not work. You need to create multidimensional array as given in documentation from server side. Iterate through List<Object> and create array of array. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549399/c-sharp-creating-an-array-of-arrays