# How do I create an array of byte arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm kind of new to c++ and my question might have a pretty easy solution, but I couldn't figure it out by myself.

Let's say I have two byte arrays **a** and **b**. Each of them contains six bytes.
Now I want to introduce a new array **c** which should contain **a** and **b**.

This is how I tried it:

```
byte a[] = {B11111111, B10010000, B10011000, B10010100, B10010010, B11110001};
byte b[] = {B11111111, B10000001, B10000001, B10000001, B10000001, B11111111};

byte c[2][6] = {{a},{b}};
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
invalid conversion from 'byte' to 'byte'
```

Comment: Never mind that you're confusing addition and multiplication (or maybe I should say unions and products), but the solution I'm envisaging uses several traits to extract array sizes and templates of variable numbers of index packs to initialize a single union array from arbitrary constituents. I think that might be a bit more involved than you were looking for.

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. A byte array is an array of bytes. An array of byte arrays is an array of arrays.

Comment: So, the question should be "how to create an array of byte arrays". It seems I can't edit questions jet. But there must be a smple solution to this anyway.

Comment: in c# it works like I tried it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549399/c-sharp-creating-an-array-of-arrays how can I do this in c++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
byte a[] = {B11111111, B10010000, B10011000, B10010100, B10010010, B11110001};
byte b[] = {B11111111, B10000001, B10000001, B10000001, B10000001, B11111111};

byte* c[2] = {a,b};
```

But it would be cleaner to just do a multidimensional array directly:

```
byte c[2][6] = {
  {B11111111, B10010000, B10011000, B10010100, B10010010, B11110001},
  {B11111111, B10000001, B10000001, B10000001, B10000001, B11111111}
};
```

Comment: This works. Can you explain why it is cleaner to do it directly and what exactly does byte*. I have to create the multidimensional array later in the code because a and b represent bitmaps for letters and c is a word. Which word it is, should be variable.

Comment: `byte* c[2]` is an array holding 2 `byte` pointers.  A `byte[]` array can be degraded into a `byte*` pointer.  So `c` is merely pointing at the starting memory addresses of `a` and `b`, rather than making copies of them.

Comment: It is cleaner if you're simply declaring these at the top of your code somewhere, since it's all in one, simple object without any unnecessary intermediary objects (e.g. a and b).


However, if you have a and b anyway and just want to hold them together, then the first solution makes more sense.


As Remy explained, byte * c[2] is just an array of byte*, so each entry in c[] is a pointer - and hence an array - in itself. You can think of byte a[] as being the same as byte *a.

Answer (score 6):

Raw arrays are a bit annoying. Use `std::array` instead:

```
using std::array;
array<byte,6> a = {B11111111, B10010000, B10011000, B10010100, B10010010, B11110001};
array<byte,6> b = {B11111111, B10000001, B10000001, B10000001, B10000001, B11111111};
array<array<byte,6>,2> c = {a, b};
```

<sup>`std::array` was introduced in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)</sup>

Comment: This sounds like a good solution but I'm wirting the code for an arduino and I get the following error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token.

Comment: This solution is also a coorect suggestion. Arduino doesn't support std::array and std::vector. I marked the pointer solution as the right one because it's a good solution and it works for me. Anyway, using std::array might be a better soloution in some other cases. I will vote +1 as soon as my reputation allows it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do a for loop to copy the 2 arrays into the third,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   c[0][i] = a[i];
   c[1][i] = b[i];
}
```